# What do you use to clean oil off of drive belt

Tags: oil-leak, belt

a power steering hose leaked near my drive belt and it is squealing a bit.  I have fixed the leaky hose and need to clean up the mess.

What can I use to clean the drive belt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick googling reveals that drive belts may be damaged by oil leaks. Thus, I would change the drive belt instead of trying to clean it. Drive belts are cheap, but the trouble caused by a failed drive belt is very annoying. If the leak has been there for a long amount time, especially then I would heavily consider changing the drive belt instead of cleaning it.

If you clean the drive belt, you need to use a solvent that is capable of dissolving oil but will not damage the rubber of the drive belt. Quick googling reveals that ehow.com recommends a soapy water solution to clean oil from a drive belt (http://www.ehow.com/info_12039924_can-clean-oil-drive-belt.html). This is probably good advice, as more effective solvents may damage the rubber of the drive belt.